# improve concurrency of named channel in spring xd

Tags: spring-xd

I have 2 stream like below and transport is rabbit

```
stream1 source|processor|processor>namedchannel

stream2 namedchannel>processor|processor|sink
```

I see that lot of message is clogged in namedchannel and i like to retrieve more message from named Channel.For source and processor modules i increased concurrency but I am not sure what should be done for named channel

Answer (score 0):

Set the concurrency on the first module (`processor`) ...

```
xd:>stream create foo --definition "time > queue:foo" --deploy
Created and deployed new stream 'foo'
xd:>stream create bar --definition "queue:foo > log"
Created new stream 'bar'
xd:>stream deploy bar --properties module.log.consumer.concurrency=2
Deployed stream 'bar'
```

You currently can't set concurrency on a `topic:` named channel - that is fixed in 1.3.1 due soon.